# How to ignore black bars on fitviewport(LibGdx) when getting coordinates?

Tags: java, libgdx, touch, coordinates, viewport

I have a problem that can't resolve. I use a stage in my game with FitViewport style.

```
stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
```

But there's a problem when I'm trying get the touchdown coordinates while black bars appear on screen (if the screen has the right ratio there's no problem).

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) 
{
    xTouch = (int) (screenX * SCREEN_WIDTH/Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    yTouch = (int) ((SCREEN_HEIGHT) - screenY * (SCREEN_HEIGHT)/Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

The coordinates that I get with this method, give the position on screen, not on my game world. camera.unproject does the same thing.
My question is, How can I ignore the black bars to get the position on my game world? I spent a lot of time searching but I did not find any useful solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a Vector2 handy so you don't have to create new ones each time:

```
private Vector2 tmpVec2 = new Vector2();
```

Then use viewport's unproject method:

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int   button) {
    stage.getViewport().unproject(tmpVec2.set(screenX, screenY));
    xTouch = tmpVec2.x;
    yTouch = tmpVec2.y;
}
```

Comment: +1. As a little sidenote to understand the difference: Viewport.unproject() uses a "special" version of Camera.unproject (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-float-float-float-float-) where you basically supply the additional information of the size of the black bars.